# how do i align image view left of button programically?

Tags: android

how do i align  image view left of button programically? in this code below i genrate  button and image view programicallybut image view is show below of buton how do i set right of button image view??

```
public class MainActivity1 extends Activity {
public  static Bitmap yourSelectedImage = null;

ImageView imageView1;
ContentValues newCon = new ContentValues();
public static byte[] blob = null;
public static long reqId;
int i;

  LinearLayout btnLO;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main1);





     btnLO = new LinearLayout(MainActivity1.this);

     LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsLO = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                             LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
     // button margins
     paramsLO.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
     // button height/width *pixels*
     paramsLO.height = 75;
     paramsLO.width = 75;

     btnLO.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
     btnLO.setBackgroundColor(5); // not working correctly

     //buttons
     for (i =0;i <j;i++)
     {
     final Button b1 = new Button(MainActivity1.this);
     final ImageView imageView = new ImageView(MainActivity1.this);



     b1.setText(reqdata[i].getSpinnerText());
     b1.setTag(reqdata[i].getValue());
     btnLO.addView(b1, paramsLO);        
     btnLO.addView(imageView, paramsLO);

     b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
            {
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {               
                    reqId =  
   Long.valueOf(reqdata[btnLO.indexOfChild(b1)/2].getValue()).longValue();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity1.this, reqId+"", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

     }

     final Button b2 = new Button(MainActivity1.this);
     b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
     {
         public void onClick(View v) 
         {              
            }
     }); 
     btnLO.addView(b2, paramsLO);
     btnLO.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);


     this.addContentView(btnLO, new LayoutParams());







  }
```

Comment: Use 
btnLO.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
LinearLayout li=new LinearLayout(this);
     li.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
     final Button b1 = new Button(MainActivity1.this);
     final ImageView imageView = new ImageView(MainActivity1.this);



     b1.setText(reqdata[i].getSpinnerText());
     b1.setTag(reqdata[i].getValue());
     li.addView(b1, paramsLO);        
     li.addView(imageView, paramsLO);

     btnLO.addView(li);
```

ScrollView sc=new ScrollView(this);
sc.addView(btnLO);

remember this must be done outside for loop.

this is how you need to add button and image to your layout inside for loop

Comment: but is create all 3 button and image view horizntally not like this way

button imageview
button image view
button imageview

Comment: ok then create another linearlayout like btnLO you have created with btnLO.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL) i.e horizontal layout and then instead of image add this layout to the btnLo layout

Comment: line 1    button imageview
line2    button   imageview
line3    button     imageview

Comment: is again same is create in same line all 6 items like this

button imageview  button image view  button imageview

Comment: no no is fine now i  did    btnLO.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL)   ur code is nice is working now
just tell me how do i add scroll view in this code so suppose if i crete 10 button and image view hw is scroll??

Comment: how to add scroll view programically??

Comment: is not working i do like this

   ScrollView sc=new ScrollView(this);

  btnLO.addView(li);
      
      sc.addView(btnLO);